# How to make Apache Kafka Client Id required for producer and consumer?

Tags: apache-kafka, clientid

What do I need to include to make my Apache Kafka Client Id required for both producer and consumer?

Comment: must use authentication [kafka auth](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_amq/7.5/html/using_amq_streams_on_rhel/configuring_kafka#con-kafka-authentication-str) ... [oauth](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_amq/7.5/html/using_amq_streams_on_rhel/configuring_kafka#oauth-jwt-str)

Comment: Hi @Mihal By, Thank you for your suggestion. Can you explain a little bit about the whole cycle and give an example?

Comment: I find simply and clear [article](https://developer.ibm.com/technologies/messaging/tutorials/kafka-authn-authz/)  or [use encription and authentication with ssl(without acl)](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka/authentication_ssl.html) it must work for all kafka platform not only Confluent.

Comment: @MihalBy, Thank you for sharing the docs. It's really helpful :)